# What character encoding is best for writing to a file in Python for only bits and newline (0, 1, '\n'), for space-conserving purposes?

Tags: python, types, file-io, character-encoding, binary

I intend to write data to a file using Python, which data happens to be composed entirely of Boolean values (i.e. binary 0/1) and newline characters.

What I attempted was this:

1) naming the file with a .BIN extension and using the "wb" flag in the file object creation.

2) use `.write(bytes(0/1))` on the numeric values and `.write(bytes(('\n').encode()))` for the newline char respectively

3) wrote in about a hundred 0's and a hundred 1's, along with 5 newline characters into the file.

the final file size was still way too large - 104 bytes when I expected 200 bits + 5 * 2 bytes (since newline is 2 bytes). So 35 bytes total.

What's going on?

Comment: Show your code. But I have bad news for you up front. Saving "a bit" into a file does not work, it'll always going to be a *byte*. It's the same thing as with strings: writing "a" string `Hello there!` into a file will result in *twelve bytes* being written, not "one item" with a resulting size of '1'.

Comment: But... that with the ```Hello there!``` string is just expected behaviour; it is not related to my issue at all!

Comment: I'm not sure what size data you'll be working with or your compression requirements, but you'll probably have a lot more luck just using the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/gzip.html) module than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @Alexander: it is. You are expecting that `write` writes single bits. My counterexample, which you seem to properly understand, is to point out that Python does not write "single strings". You are thinking in bits but Python only writes bytes. Still awaiting your faulty code – maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, I am not expecting that ```write``` writes single bits by default. That's what I **want** it to do via applying appropriate modifications, so that a file that contains the string (for example) ```0010101010101010``` does not interpret each bit as a character / integer, but as just that -- **a binary bit**, which also takes the **size of a bit** on disk. In ASCII and Unicode, that can't be changed, as each symbol is inherently a character that takes 8 bits, i.e. 1 byte. I'm asking if there's a type of encoding that **can** interpret this string as a **"bit stream"**.

Comment: There isn't, other than *bytes*. Encoding and decoding happens in your program, not on disk. Have you thought about the additional problem of distinguishing your `\n` from the perfectly normal bit sequence `00001010`? Both would be written to disk as a single decimal value `10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing bits to a file is a problem, because buffers talk in bytes, not bits. Hence, if you want to write bits, you have to combine them into bytes, which might also mean you have to include padding, in case you have an uneven number of bits. You could manually write bits2bytes and bytes2bits yourself, or use a module. I believe the module you are looking for is the bitarray module which contains these and similar functions (might need to pip install).

Note, that because of padding, it is common practice to also write the length of the padding that you use at the start of the file. If you don't include this value, then you won't know how much padding is used. Because bytes are 8 bits, then we can have at most 7 bits of padding. Hence, we need 3 bits of space at the start of the file to know how much padding was added.

```
from bitarray import bitarray

def bits2file(filename,bits):
    pad_len = 8-(len(bits)+3)%8
    file_bits = bitarray(bin(pad_len)[2:].zfill(3)) + bits
    f = open(filename,'wb')
    file_bits.tofile(f)
    f.close()

def file2bits(filename):
    file_bits = bitarray()
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    file_bits.fromfile(f)
    f.close()
    pad_len = int(file_bits[:3].to01(),2)
    return file_bits[3:-pad_len]

bits = bitarray('101011111')
bits2file('temp',bits)
bits = file2bits('temp')
print(bits)

bits = bitarray('10000100010100')
bits2file('temp',bits)
bits = file2bits('temp')
print(bits)
```

Comment: I think you are somewhat getting to what I require. See my new replay to @usr2564301 in the thread above; hopefully that should clarify enough what I require.

Comment: Some of the statements you have made don't sound right. In particular, we should strongly emphasize that ALL buffers talk in bytes. This means that python byte-strings write to RAM in bytes, python strings are written in bytes, python ints/floats use bytes. In fact, even your processor fills their buffers for processing in bytes and performs exclusively BYTE operations. The OS writes files by bytes. FYI, writing things and processing things in bits actually causes your computer more work. Anyway, try my code above and see if "temp" file is the kind of file you are looking for.